# QTableView + QCompleter delegate returns wrong value

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qtableview, qcompleter

I'm using Qt (C++), specifically I have a table that auto-completes using a `QCompleter`. I'm **very** new to Qt and struggling with this.

My problem is that even though the `QCompleter` shows the correct values, the data it returns is always the data for the first element.

For example, if I have the following data (fields separated by dashes, data made up):

```
1-David-197598713-Los Angeles
2-Daniel-1933398713-NYC
3-Don-1975555-Argentina
```

And I type **D**, the QCompleter shows the 3 options, but regardless of which I pick, this happens:

1. The actual cell edits "correctly" (the value reflects what's been picked)
2. The callback receives the **WRONG** value (always the ID of the first element)

So in this case I'd always get (Assuming the name is the autocomplete field):
1-Daniel-197598713-Los Angeles **or** 1-Don-197598713-Los Angeles **or** 1-David-197598713-Los Angeles

Also, for some motive the setEditorData procedure does nothing at all (if I comment it, the behavior doesn't change at all)

This is my entire delegate source:

```
productNameDelegate::productNameDelegate(QObject *parent) : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}


QWidget *productNameDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
    const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
    QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    QCompleter *q = new QCompleter(db::getProductsNames());
    q->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    q->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
    editor->setCompleter(q);
    return editor;
}

void productNameDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                     const QModelIndex &index) const
 {  //TODO this procedure doesn't affect the code at all
     QString value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
     QLineEdit *LineEdit = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
     LineEdit->setText(value);
 }

void productNameDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit *LineEdit = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    QString value = LineEdit->text();
    int code=LineEdit->completer()->currentIndex().data(Qt::UserRole).toInt(); //FIXME: siempre devuelve el primer elemento de la lista
    if (index.column()==2 && index.row()>=6 && index.row() <= 25)
        m->addProducto(code, index.row());
    model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);

}


void productNameDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
     const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
 {
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}


void productNameDelegate::setModel(factura* m) {
    this->m=m;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Qt::UserRole` to read the data of `QCompleter`? Also why do you use `Qt::EditRole` in `setEditorData` and `setModelData` ?

Comment: I followed various examples on the web and all did this; when I save my data in the model I save it as Qt::UserRole